# how to iterate on enum properties of a record type object in a type-safe way?

Tags: typescript

The following code works (but requires silencing a type checking error):

```
enum ParametricTable {
    A = 'a',
    B = 'b'
}

type Database = Record<ParametricTable, number>;

const database: Database = {
    [ParametricTable.A]: 41,
    [ParametricTable.B]: 42
};


for (let parametric_table in database) {
    // @ts-expect-error
    const value: number = database[parametric_table];
    if (value===undefined)
        throw 'weird - this should never be undefined';
    else
        console.log(value);

}
```

The above code duly prints 41 and 42 on stdout.

The below code typechecks, but results in the exception being thrown:

```
enum ParametricTable {
    A = 'a',
    B = 'b'
}

type Database = Record<ParametricTable, number>;

const database: Database = {
    [ParametricTable.A]: 41,
    [ParametricTable.B]: 42
};


for (let parametric_table in database) {
    const value: number = database[ParametricTable[parametric_table as keyof typeof ParametricTable]];
    if (value===undefined)
        throw 'weird - this should never be undefined';
    else
        console.log(value);

}
```

What is the proper way to iterate over the properties of the `database` object in the above example?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well that issue is related to the type checking in `for in` loop. Details are in [here](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/issues/3500). Which causes the left-hand side to be a string or any type. A workaround is needed to be used like below :

```
const enum ParametricTable {
    A = 'a',
    B = 'b'
    
}
type Database = Record<ParametricTable, number>;

const database :{ [key in  ParametricTable ] : number } = {
    [ParametricTable.A]: 41,
    [ParametricTable.B]: 42
};

let parametric_table :keyof typeof database;
for (  parametric_table in database) {   // note that there is no let here
    const value: number = database[parametric_table]; // no implicity any errors.
    if (value===undefined)
        throw 'weird - this should never be undefined';
    else
        console.log(value);

}
```

[Playground Link](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?jsx=0#code/MYewdgzgLgBApmArgWxgBQIYCcPLlLAS2ABUMAjAGzhgG8AoGJmAQRgF4YByDLgGkbMAQh27kugpvQC+9KAE8ADjQAiGKBQwQanAEpxQWACYAeTDjwFiZKnD4wkycnCwA+ANz16oSLCPrNbRgALloYAG0Aazh5GEIwJnNcfCJSCmoYAF0QhxRnLBhpUQZmCKTLVJtqADoWTOCYABYARgFS8PKU63S4aqF6poAmGU96alhFbGSrYAB9DVsQ6PkQADMYBWU1mH8FrThPVZACgAomSYsuuYWM+J2A8n2ASjpmAHo3hxAoGigAC3UGz+LhohAgXxg4xgwKwcEkMB80BgADcMJREHAGo58qJdoE4OELtNUvMepl3DAPhDCMhFJRiIQFDAMGBYi4sMcINV4YR1idUei4OxhYgwEY4Kt4nAjE94aV-hyAO7cRVwQjGGAAWiBYJgED+IEQlCMDjgyJcMGcMFF4slYGlXE8pTglG0cuYiJANUoIAA5vy0RinqNZPQgA)